# BIBO stability and input at system's pole

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, theory

My understanding of BIBO stability is that if a bounded input is applied to a discrete-time, linear, time-invariant BIBO system, the output will also be bounded. A sufficient condition for this is that the poles of the transfer function are within the unit circle.

Suppose I have a system with the transfer function 
$$
H(z)={(1−2z^{−1})(1−{\frac{1}{6}} z^{−1}) \over (1−\frac{1}{2}z^{−1})(1−\frac{1}{3}z^{−1})}
$$
The poles of this system are within the unit circle and so is a BIBO stable system.

If I apply an input of $x[n]=(\frac{1}{3})^n$, which is bounded, the output would involve $H(\frac{1}{3})=\infty$, which is unbounded - i.e. a bounded input produced an unbounded output.

Obviously, there is something amiss in my understanding here, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal $x[n] = (\frac{1}{3})^n$ is not bounded. As $n \to -\infty$, $x[n] \to \infty$; therefore, the system's response to your candidate signal $x[n]$ has no bearing on its BIBO stability.

A bounded, causal version of the signal (and likely what you were thinking) is $x_b[n] = (\frac{1}{3})^n u[n]$, where $u[n]$ is the unit step function. The response of the system to this signal is bounded as you would expect.

Comment: D'oh! D'oh! D'oh!!!!!

Comment: Also, you don't get the response of the system to $x[n]$ by evaluating $H(z)$ at some value of $z$... instead, you take the z-transform of $x[n]$, multiply it with $H(z)$, and call the result $Y(z)$.  Now, you can do an inverse transform to get $y[n]$, which you will see is bounded.

Comment: I understood from [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25100/output-of-a-discrete-time-lti-system-different-form-than-input/25103#25103) that the output of a system when the input is a 'pure' exponential such as $\frac{1}{3}^n$ would involve evaluating $H(\frac{1}{3})$. If the input was $\frac{1}{3}^nu[n]$, then it would be as you say

Comment: @CMDoolittle: The OP is correct; the $z$ transform can be used in this way since exponential functions are the eigenfunctions of discrete-time LTI systems. The value $H(z)$ corresponds to the eigenvalue associated with the function $x[n] = z^{-n}$.

Comment: Wow.  I did not know that.  Thanks y'all!

Comment: @JasonR: just a little correction: $H(z)$ is the eigenvalue associated with the function $z^n$, not $z^{-n}$.

Comment: @MattL.: You're correct. Sorry for the typo.